# How to check if user is authorized in code?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Within a component we can use `AuthorizeView` but what is the equivalent when we need to check if user is authorized in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [inject the AuthenticationStateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authenticationstateprovider-service) into a component as demonstrated in the docs.

This also works:

`AuthenticationState` can be used. Wrap the `<Router>` in a `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` component and do something like this in your component:

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authStateTask {get; set;}

   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authstate = await authStateTask;
        var someRole = authstate.User.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "your_role").Value;

       //if role is OK do something....
    }
}
```